# Selenium selection By.Xpath in between a div

Tags: java, maven, selenium, xpath

I am sure this question has been asked many times, and there are several examples of it. However, with there being so many different selection options, Id like the most clear cut way to handle selections of this sort. If the easiest way is not to use an xpath that is fine too.. Here is the puny HTML segment...

```
<div class="atcui-text atcui-align-right">SAVED DOCUMENTS</div>
```

I want to be able to identify it by the 'SAVED DOCUMENTS'.. what would be the easiest way to do this? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with Xpath:

```
 driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'atcui-text') and contains(text(), 'SAVED DOCUMENTS')]"));
```

or if class is going to be dynamic then search only by text:

```
driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("//div[contains(text(), 'SAVED DOCUMENTS')]"));
```

This is c# hope you can translate it to java...

Comment: Java: `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(), 'SAVED DOCUMENTS')]"));`